# Android - Update Location every x minutes

Tags: android, location, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

I'm pretty new to android, and this is my first post here, so please be kind! :-)

I'm trying to create a service which runs in the background and does a location update every x minutes. To run it every x minutes I'm using the AlarmManager, as described here: [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Here's what I've got:

```
package com.example.service1;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class Scheduler extends BroadcastReceiver{

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();




    //Code which is executed every X seconds/minutes

    getLocation(context);

    //End of Code
    wl.release();

}

public void setScheduler(Context context) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Scheduler.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 20, pi);

}


//Method to get the Location

public void getLocation(Context context) {

    Log.e("null","getLocation");
    locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e(null, "location change");
            makeUseOfLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };

}

//Method to work with the location Data; Instance of Point is created
public void makeUseOfLocation(Location location) {
    Log.e(null,"makeuse");

    Log.e(null,location.getLatitude() + "");
}

}
```

`getLocation()` is called every 20 seconds, but then it never runs `onLocationChanged()` (I use the EmulatorControl in Eclipse to change the location).

I had the same problem before when I used the `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of the `AlarmManager`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code I never see the call to [locationManager.requestLocationUpdates()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29) with your listener as an argument.

This means that your listener is never registered with the location manager, and therefore does not get called.

You probably only want to register one listener, instead of registering a new one every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 protected void updateNotification() {
         LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationlistener();

         lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, normallocationwait, 0.250f, locationListener);
         location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
   }

   private class MyLocationlistener implements LocationListener {

     public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
         if(location!=null){
             if(location.hasAccuracy()){
                   dumpLocation(location);
             }else{
                   dumpLocation(location);
            }
         } 
     }

     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
         Log.v("Loc Update","\nProvider disabled: " + provider);
     }

     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
         Log.v("Loc Update","\nProvider enabled: " + provider);
     }

     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
         Log.v("Loc Update","\nProvider status changed: " + provider + ", status="
                    + status + ", extras=" + extras);
     }
```